# how get index of HTML Table for given element using delphi

Tags: html, delphi, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi 2009 and I want to find index of HTML table which contains given element.

So, in the application, which I created, I use web browser to see the web page. I want to select element from this page and want to get Index of table which contains this element.

If someone can do it, please help me

Comment: Are you asking how to find the row and column coordinates within a table of a selected one of its cells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the browser's DOM interfaces, locate the [`IHTMLElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx) interface of the desired HTML element as needed, then use its `parentElement` property to get its parent element, repeating as needed, until you find an element that supports the [`IHTMLTableCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741764(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.  Its `cellIndex` property will tell you the index of the cell within its row.  Keep iterating the `parentElement` chain until you find an element that supports the [`IHTMLTableRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741726(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.  Its `rowIndex` property will tell you the index of the row within its table.  If you need to access the table itself, keep iterating the `parentElement` chain until you find an element that supports the [`IHTMLTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768620(v=vs.85).aspx) interface.